# Not Able to parse date filed from CSV file, It is giving Illegal assignment from String to Date

Tags: apex, csv, import

I am facing issue with importing Date field from CSV file.
I am giving the date as mm/dd/yyyy in CSV file, and getting error as "Illegal assignment from String to Date".

Below is my code:

```
public static void Dataload(List<Id> CaseListFromTrigger){  
    string emailMessageId;        
    string str;
    Blob blobbody;              
    List<Sobject> recordstoupload;
    List<String> headervalues = new List<String>();
    string nameFile;
    String[] filelines = new String[]{};
    string AtachParId;
    String csvContent;
    boolean doSentEmail = false;

emailMessageId=[SELECT Id, ParentId FROM EmailMessage where ParentId = :CaseListFromTrigger].Id;
system.debug('***emailMessageId-->'+emailMessageId);

for(Case casedes: [Select Description, Subject from Case where id =: CaseListFromTrigger]){
    str= (casedes.Subject).trim();            
} 

for(Attachment Atch:[SELECT  Id, ParentId,Name,body  FROM Attachment where ParentId = :emailMessageId]){
    blobbody= Atch.Body;
    AtachParId=Atch.ParentId; 
}
system.debug('description--->'+str);                                
System.debug('\n Selected Object--->'+str);

if(str == null)
{
    System.debug('If object is not present');
}
else{
    //Convert the uploaded file which is in BLOB format into a string
     nameFile =blobToString( blobbody,'ISO-8859-1');

    //Now sepatate every row of the excel file
    filelines = nameFile.split('\n');
    Map<String,Schema.SObjectType> gd = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
    Schema.SObjectType objecttypeinfo=gd.get(str);

    //Iterate through every line and create a Account record for each row
    recordstoupload= new List<Sobject>();
    headerValues =new List<String>();
    headerValues = filelines[0].trim().split(',');
    System.debug('**headerValues**'+headerValues );

    for (Integer i=1;i<filelines.size();i++)
    {
        String[] inputvalues = new String[]{};
        inputvalues = filelines[i].split(',');
        System.debug('**inputvalues**'+inputvalues);
        sObject sObj = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(str).newSObject() ;
        for(Integer j=0;j<headerValues.size();j++){
            System.debug('**headerValues[j]**'+headerValues[j]+'***inputvalues[j]**'+inputvalues[j]);
            sObj.put(headerValues[j],String.ValueOf(inputvalues[j])) ;                 
        }
        System.debug('**sObj**'+sObj);
        recordstoupload.add(sObj);
    }

    csvContent = headerValues +'\n';
    Database.SaveResult[] srList = Database.insert(recordstoupload, false);
    for (Database.SaveResult sr : srList) {
        if (sr.isSuccess()) {
        System.debug('**SUCCESS**'+sr.getId());
            csvContent = csvContent+'\n';
        }
        else{
            for(Database.Error err : sr.getErrors()) {
                csvContent = csvContent + sr.getErrors()  + '\n';
                System.debug('If object is not present Exception'+sr.getErrors());
            }
        }                
    }       
}       
}



public static String blobToString(Blob input, String inCharset){
    String hex = EncodingUtil.convertToHex(input);
    System.assertEquals(0, hex.length() & 1);
    final Integer bytesCount = hex.length() >> 1;
    String[] bytes = new String[bytesCount];
    for(Integer i = 0; i < bytesCount; ++i)
        bytes[i] =  hex.mid(i << 1, 2);
    return EncodingUtil.urlDecode('%' + String.join(bytes, '%'), inCharset);
}
```

Please let me know if i am missing anything.

[image]

Comment: You'd need to typecast the date value

Comment: Hi @RahulSharma, Please let me know how i can type cast the date value. If u can help me with code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to parse the string as a date using `Date.valueOf()` to make it a date before you can assign it to a date field.

I would use `SobjecType.getDescribe().fields.getMap()` to get a list of fields, loop over them to find the field currently being worked, check whether or not it's a date field, and then parse accordingly.

UPDATE with example:

I would change this:

```
for(Integer j=0;j<headerValues.size();j++){
        System.debug('**headerValues[j]**'+headerValues[j]+'***inputvalues[j]**'+inputvalues[j]);
        sObj.put(headerValues[j],String.ValueOf(inputvalues[j])) ;                 
    }
```

to something like this:

```
Map<String,Schema.SObjectField> fields = sobj.SObjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
for(Integer j=0;j<headerValues.size();j++){
    Schema.DescribeFieldResult currentField = fields.get(headerValues[j]).getDescribe();
    if(currentField.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.Date){
        sObj.put(headerValues[j],String.ValueOf(Date.parse(inputvalues[j]))) ;
    } else {
        sObj.put(headerValues[j],String.ValueOf(inputvalues[j])) ;
    }                     
}
```

Comment: Hi @John Towers, I didn't get u. It will be helpful if you can provide the specific line where u want me to add this code. I tried using Date.ValueOf() at line 54 "sObj.put(headerValues[j],Date.ValueOf(inputvalues[j]));".

Comment: @shashankgupta Right, you can't parse everything as a date. You need to determine which fields on the object are date fields and parse those as dates. The rest should be parsed as strings. I'll update the answer with an example today when I have a chance.

Comment: Thank you John... Really Appreciated... Till the time i will try to figure out how i can check where i am getting the date field in data.

Comment: Okay, answer is updated with a sample. You'll probably want to do more checking than that (e.g., make sure the value is in the right format and not null) but this should work as a basic example.

Comment: Thank you for update in code but i tried using this and it is not parsing my date. Still getting same error.

Comment: What code did you end up using? Exactly what value is the error being thrown on?